# PowerShell and Excel Issue when Automating

Tags: sql-server-2008, powershell, excel, vba

I am facing a curious problem.

When I ran this code :

```
$Excel = New-Object -Com Excel.Application 
$book = $Excel.Workbooks.Add()
[threading.thread]::CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = 'en-US'
sleep 10
$book.saveas("c:\Temp\test.xlsx")
$Excel.quit()
Stop-Process -Name "Excel*"
```

in PowerGui, POwerSHell host..anywhere, it works beatiful.

If I put into a  .bat and calls powerhsell  "c:\temp\excel.ps1" works fine too.

But If i try to schedule this guy into schedule task  or run by a sql server job type cmd the error happens :

Message
Exception calling "SaveAs" with "1" argument(s): "SaveAs method of Workbook cla
ss failed"

Only when It is called by SQL Server Jobs ( that is a simple cmd command too and the line is the same as the .bat  powerhsell  "c:\temp\excel.ps1" ) the error happens.

What it can be ? I tried  change the fileformat..etc..and nothing

Thanks Guys :)

Comment: Are the filepaths as per your example are they different in the real case? Are the tests on the same machine? Can you try and run the sql job as your credentials and test it?

Comment: Yes..in the same machine. Only not works when it runs sheduled. I think it is something with culture info, but I am changing the culture info too. Really dont know

Comment: Also the SQl Agent Account I put as domain admin to discartd security too. Juts not works

Comment: Add a try catch as log the exception if any. See this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2182666/powershell-2-0-try-catch-how-to-access-the-exception

Comment: That is the exception. Exception calling "SaveAs" with "1" argument(s): "SaveAs method of Workbook cla ss failed" +     $book.saveas <<<< ("c:\Temp\test.xlsx")
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ComMethodTargetInvocation

Comment: Just Tried in the Windows Scheduler Task and the same error happens. run it by domain admin account.

Comment: Have a look at this : http://stillpearling.blogspot.co.nz/2009/02/more-powershell-adventures.html

Comment: You have to create a folder (or two on a 64bit-windows):
 
(32Bit, always)
 
C:\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile\Dektop
 
(64Bit)
 
C:\Windows\SysWOW64\config\systemprofile\Desktop
 

The solution is in the http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winserverpowershell/thread/aede572b-4c1f-4729-bc9d-899fed5fad02  Thanks A LOT

Comment: @lj - please put the solution in an answer for other users. PS well done!

Answer (score 7):

The Solution is :

You have to create a folder (or two on a 64bit-windows):

(32Bit, always)

C:\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile\Dektop

(64Bit)

C:\Windows\SysWOW64\config\systemprofile\Desktop

The solution is in the Forum :

[Solution Forum MS](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winserverpowershell/thread/aede572b-4c1f-4729-bc9d-899fed5fad02)